# Entity Framework, LinqToSQL and sql injection

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, sql-injection

Is it possible for a project using entirely LinqToSQL or Entity Framewok to suffer from SQL Injection.

I think that probably not because the SQL that the ORM generates should be sql-injection free. But I'm not sure.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473173/will-using-linq-to-sql-help-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Not exactly duplicate as this also asks for Entity Framework. Also the answers are actually saying that there is a possibilty for attack under some circumstances

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use those frameworks as intended, i.e. the entities/tables directly, then no. All string comparisons (i.e. `where name = 'smith'` ) are parameterized.

The only vulnerable spots are:

- any string can be executed directly against the context.  `dbContext.ExecuteQuery();` with any kind of destructive string.
- a stored procedure executing dynamic SQL using any parameters given

Comment: In VS2012 out of the box. _ Where(a => a.column == "Quote'") _ did translate to a bound var _ @1=[Extent1].[column] _. And _ Where(a => a.column != "Quote'") _ translated to _ N'Quote'''=[Extent1].[column] _

Answer (score 3):

"It depends".

Plain LINQ queries against L2S or EF entities are injection safe, but you could always call a stored procedure or function that is not injection safe.

That would clearly be an edge case, but yes it happens that people write SPs/functions that are open to injection (composing SQL-in-strings with parameter values inside the proc).