# Possible SQL Injection when using contains with EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t-sql

I've noticed that when using Contains in EF

```
.Where(i => myListOfStrings.Contains(i.Value))
```

The generated SQL looks like this

```
IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
```

Since the values are not parameterized, isn't it possible to inject some SQL?

Comment: Where are you viewing the generated SQL from? Profiler? I would assume EF is doing the relevant string encoding of the values before passing the query on.

Comment: Try it! Pass in something like `') OR 1=1--`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473173/will-using-linq-to-sql-help-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @L-Four yes that I know, but in case of contains it doesn't create any parameters.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft yes from profiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not just mindlessly construct IN statement from your `Contains`. At very least it will escape single quotes (by doubling them). Suppose you want to inject something like "') OR 1=1--" like suggested in comments, assuming that it will be converted to:

```
where ... IN ('') OR 1 = 1 -- the rest
```

But because single quotes are escaped that will be:

```
where ... IN (''') OR 1 = 1 --' -- the rest
```

So we are safe here, because your whole statement is treated as string.